# ERROR [org.keycloak.services] : Failed to send email: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported

Tags: keycloak

I am having keycloak running on docker container version 15.0.2 , Java version 1.8.0_181
OS - Windows server 2016 10.0

ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0029: Failed to send email: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2

[Click here to see details of Keycloak server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGV1c.jpg)